# R programming and shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
ui <- fluidPage(
 sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(radioButtons(
   "fiscal","Quarter:",c("2015Q1","2015Q2","2015Q3","2015Q4","2016Q1"))),                    
    mainPanel({
     plotOutput('plot')
    })))
 server <- function (input , output  )
{
myread <- function ()  
{ 
inFile <- input$file1
if (is.null(inFile))
return(NULL)
mydata <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
return (mydata)
}

plotType <- function(type) 
{
  switch(type)
         Q12015 <- { mydataq1 <- reactive (myread())
                   x <- reactive(data.frame(mydataq1()))
                    y <- reactive ({x()[x()$Fiscal.Quarter=="2015Q1",]
                  resources <- factor (y()$Resource.Name)
           stan <- tapply (y()$Standard.Hours,resources, sum , na.rm=TRUE)
           bil <- tapply (y()$Billable.Hours,resources, sum , na.rm=TRUE)
           bu <- bil*100 / stan
           mp <- barplot (bu,col=colors(27),las=2,yaxt="n",ylim=c(0,200))
           bu<- round(bu,2)
           text(mp, bu,labels=bu, pos = 3)
         })
         output$plot <- renderPlot ({ y () })

         }
         Q22015= { mydataq1 <- reactive (myread())
         x <- reactive(data.frame(mydataq1()))
         y <- reactive ({x()[x()$Fiscal.Quarter=="2015Q2",]
           resources <- factor (y()$Resource.Name)
           stan <- tapply (y()$Standard.Hours,resources, sum , na.rm=TRUE)
           bil <- tapply (y()$Billable.Hours,resources, sum , na.rm=TRUE)
           bu <- bil*100 / stan
           mp <- barplot (bu,col=colors(27),las=2,yaxt="n",ylim=c(0,200))
           bu<- round(bu,2)
           text(mp, bu,labels=bu, pos = 3)
         })
         output$plot <- renderPlot ({ y () })

         }
         Q32015 = { mydataq1 <- reactive (myread())
         x <- reactive(data.frame(mydataq1()))
         y <- reactive ({x()[x()$Fiscal.Quarter=="2015Q3",]
           resources <- factor (y()$Resource.Name)
           stan <- tapply (y()$Standard.Hours,resources, sum , na.rm=TRUE)
           bil <- tapply (y()$Billable.Hours,resources, sum , na.rm=TRUE)
           bu <- bil*100 / stan
           mp <- barplot (bu,col=colors(27),las=2,yaxt="n",ylim=c(0,200))
           bu<- round(bu,2)
           text(mp, bu,labels=bu, pos = 3)
         })
         output$plot <- renderPlot ({ y () })

         }
      Q42015={
        mydataq1 <- reactive (myread())
        x <- reactive(data.frame(mydataq1()))
        y <- reactive ({x()[x()$Fiscal.Quarter=="2015Q4",]
          resources <- factor (y()$Resource.Name)
          stan <- tapply (y()$Standard.Hours,resources, sum , na.rm=TRUE)
          bil <- tapply (y()$Billable.Hours,resources, sum , na.rm=TRUE)
          bu <- bil*100 / stan
          mp <- barplot (bu,col=colors(27),las=2,yaxt="n",ylim=c(0,200))
          bu<- round(bu,2)
          text(mp, bu,labels=bu, pos = 3)
        })
        output$plot <- renderPlot ({ y () })
      }   
       Q12016={
      mydataq1 <- reactive (myread())
      x <- reactive(data.frame(mydataq1()))
      y <- reactive ({x()[x()$Fiscal.Quarter=="2015Q4",]
        resources <- factor (y()$Resource.Name)
        stan <- tapply (y()$Standard.Hours,resources, sum , na.rm=TRUE)
        bil <- tapply (y()$Billable.Hours,resources, sum , na.rm=TRUE)
        bu <- bil*100 / stan
        mp <- barplot (bu,col=colors(27),las=2,yaxt="n",ylim=c(0,200))
        bu<- round(bu,2)
        text(mp, bu,labels=bu, pos = 3)
      })
      output$plot <- renderPlot ({ y () })
    }
}

plotType(input$fiscal)

}
shinyApp(ui=ui ,server=server)
```

I have edited my code. Getting the following error now :-

Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't specify exactly why you need different tabs for different plots, it would be easier for the user to just view the plot for the quarter they select.

Your problem appeared to be the data read in and formatting, you should be able to easily tweak this solution below to fit your exact needs. If you you have more specific requests, please update your question and provide a reproducible example.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("file1", label = "Input File"),
      actionButton("loadFile", "Load"),
      radioButtons("fiscal", "Quarter:", c("2015Q1","2015Q2","2015Q3","2015Q4","2016Q1"))
      ),
    mainPanel({
      plotOutput("plot")
    })
  )
)

server <- function (input, output){
  mydata <- eventReactive(input$loadFile, {
    validate(
      need(input$file1, "Enter a valid filename!")
    )
    read.csv(input$file1)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    x <- mydata()
    y <- x[x$Fiscal.Quarter == input$fiscal, ]
    resources <- factor(y$Resource.Name)
    stan <- tapply(y$Standard.Hours, resources, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
    bil <- tapply(y$Billable.Hours, resources, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
    bu <- bil*100 / stan
    mp <- barplot (bu, col = colors(27), las = 2, yaxt = "n", ylim = c(0,200))
    bu<- round(bu, 2)
    text(mp, bu, labels = bu, pos = 3)
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: In the above solution the radio buttons are nowhere integrated to the plot variable. I have four different plots which is associated with each radio button .I want all the graphs in one window only with the click on radio buttons (One graph at a time)